# Mod_Rewrite for URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have been looking through questions and answer for days trying to figure out how to make this work.

So far I can get my URL to change, but it won't load the page.

I have to take

http://www.mysite.com/index.php?mode=about

And have it show up as

http://www.mysite.com/about/

So far I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mode=(.*)
RewriteRule ^ http\:\/\/\www.mysite.com\/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /(.*) /index.php?mode=%1 [L]
```

I have changed things multiple times and nothing. Most site seem to tell me I don't need the 301 redirect but then I can't get anything to work.

Comment: So the URL does change (indicating your rewrites are working) but when you end up at `/about/` the page `index.php?mode=about` doesn't load? Or do you need your rewrites fixed so it properly routes to `/about/`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I get my page error saying "Page Not Found" but it does show the correct information I want to have displayed in address bar

Comment: I say if you only leave `RewriteEngine on` and `RewriteRule /(.*) /index.php?mode=%1 [L]` and get rid of the rest, it should work.

Comment: I have tried that and that seems to be what most of the sites out there say to do, but nothing works when I take out the other parts.

Comment: Just tried it again to make sure. The site works the same as if there was no code when I remove those two lines.

Answer (score 0):

For (your) example, once you've properly routed from `mysite.com/index.php?mode=about` to `mysite.com/about`, it's now going to look at `mysite.com/about/` to find what comes next (index.py/index.html/etc).

Because there is nothing at `/about/`, you're getting a 404 error.

I don't think you can use mod_rewrite to do exactly what you're trying to achieve, without having some handling within `/about/` to actually display the page you want once you get there.

http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html

> Remember the Filesystem Always Takes Precedence
>
> The filesystem on your server will always take precedence over the
>   rewritten URL. For example, if you have a directory named “services”
>   and within that directory is a file called “design.html”, you can’t
>   have the URL redirect to “http://domain.com/services”. What happens is
>   that Apache goes into the “services” directory and doesn’t see the
>   rewrite instructions.
>
> To fix this, simply rename your directory (adding an underscore to the
>   beginning or end is a simple way to do that).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Which directory should I rename with an underscore? Does it go before or after the name?

Answer (score 0):

> I have to take
>
> http://www.mysite.com/index.php?mode=about
>
> And have it show up as
>
> http://www.mysite.com/about/

There are two very common types of rules that people want and your statement can be interpreted two ways which require different rules. I'm going to interpret your statement that you have a real, operational script at `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?mode=about`, but instead of having the user enter that "ugly" URL, you want them to be served that URL when they enter `http://www.mysite.com/about/`. To accomplish this, you would do the following:

```
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /index.php?mode=about [L]
```

Because of the potential for misunderstanding, it's best to state what you want as (1) What the user will enter into their browser and (2) what real file you want to serve them.

Comment: Nothing happens when I use what you suggested. My site acts the same as if the code is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need lines #2 & 3 & you seem to have % instead of $, try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+) /index.php?mode=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mysite.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: @Ni Ck, updated the answer with another version at the bottom ;)

Comment: I'm back to getting an Internal Server Error when I try to load the site.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Thanks for all the help.

---

#< IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# RewriteEngine on

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#< /IfModule>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?mode=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?mode=$1

Comment: I see. Although there might be tons of similar answers on this site, I would recommend to mark this answer as accepted so others would see the right answer. And you can also combine your 2 lines in one by adding ? after the closing parentheses and probably add QUERY_STRING (example: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}`), so you would not loose it in case you want to have extra vars after your new URL, for instance `/about/?anotherVar=extra` which would be same as `index.php?mode=about&anotherVar=extra`.

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks.

It won't let me check it off till tomorrow.

Comment: How can I take the second variable and mask it to? so instead of having /about/?anotherVar=extra I have /about/extra. The second variable would be on some pages not all

Comment: `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?/?$ index.php?mode=$1&anotherVar=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: I should be a little more clear. It works and it loads my page, but I lose parts of my page. I have used <?php include("template.php") ?> on the index page and the mode variable loads the content infomation into the template.php. When I go to add /oliveOil to the URL it loads the right page but does not load the template.php. Is there a solution to this or will I have to stick to using /products?productContent=oliveOil in the URL?

Comment: you probably need to post a new question or modify this one. it is not recommended to start long discussions in comments and i am not understanding what your problem is - not enough info. may be somebody else will if you explain it better

Comment: I fixed it!! It wasn't the template.php that was the issue it was all my image and css links that were the problem. Added the domain name in front and all is well. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396454/mod-rewrites-wont-go-to-404-page-not-found-for-non-existing-pages

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -d
RewriteRule  ^.*$  -  [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$  /index.php?mode=$1 [L]
```

Where the beginning still allows for other folders to be accessible.