# Mod Rewrites won't go to "404 page not found" for non existing pages

Tags: mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have the following code which works great:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&productContent=$2 [QSA]
```

My problem is when I go to a page that doesn't exist on my site ie. mysite.com/books I get the following warning error:  failed to open stream: No such file or directory. Is there a way to avoid this error and have it go to "404 Page Not Found" instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can't handle that with Apache's mod_rewrite, it's a script error and has to be taken care of by the code, php in your case.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about doing that?

Comment: judging by your error, you just need to check `if (file exists($file))` and if not redirect user to the 404 page. if you don't do good error checking in your code, you will probably run into another error after that, but may be not, but in general you just need to catch the error and do `header('Location: your-404-page.php'); die;` . Make sure there was no output on the page prior to calling the `header()` function or it will break otherwise you will need to lookup the `ob_start()` & `ob_ob_end_flush()`

Comment: Also note that many frameworks have a debug mode that displays error messages rather than normal 404 pages. You will have to turn off debug mode to see your custom 404s, 500s, etc.